# Universal apps not running and design view crashing on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

When creating a new C# universal windows project, the design view shows an unhanded exception:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[6604] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!.
```

Also, the app itself crashes with `Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll`

I am using VS 2015 Enterprise, which works fine for other types projects (WPF,...). I'm running it on Windows 10 Education.

Any idea how can this be solved? There are lots of posts with similar problems all around the web, but non of the solutions worked for me. I've also applied Update 2 and it didn't help.

Comment: Do you deploy on remote device?

Comment: No. It's really simple: I open VS, create new Universal Windows Project, and BAM, the designer crashes, and the app also crashes.

Comment: you can check this thread if it helps: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797072/designer-crashes-in-visual-studio-2013-with-system-runtime-remoting-remotingexception

sample steps suggested it to clear shadowcache
Delete all the files in the shadowcache at
take backup of this folder and then remove all contents %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the last few weeks.

As silly as it sounds, I uninstalled VS, and reinstalled.